# PHP doing SNMP walk on remote devices/clients?

Tags: php, snmp

I am trying to create a new application for our company to do an SNMP walk.

Here's what I am trying to achieve. The customer logs into our website. Clicks a button saying "Do SNMP Walk" and a PHP script will do a walk, and parse the data into the MySQL DB, and that's it.

Is this possible to do with PHP?

I was reading on http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmpwalk.php and I seen that it looks like it is, but I wasn't sure because the clients wouldn't be on the same network as the server the script is running from (we'd be using godaddy.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to SNMP walk devices in the client's network from your GoDaddy server, then the answer is no: you won't be able to do it.

SNMP is typically not passed through firewalls, so you would need to deploy your PHP code on the same network as the client.

Comment: how would I go about "deploying" it?

Comment: Basically they would need to be running a PHP server on the same network as the devices you want to access via SNMP. You could copy your code to that server and run it there, but accessing SNMP over the Internet is generally not easy without any number of strange firewall/routing tricks, if at all possible.

Comment: Aw sucks.. Thanks for your quick response though!

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong... snmp, is passed like any other data packets, unless the router is specifically configured to block it.  I frequently use it to access routers across the internet to different providers and such.

Its possible that GoDaddy has blocks on that, but I have never seen this.  You may want to install a copy of snmp on your computer and do an snmpwalk from the commandline.